# ASP.NET GridView to List with headers

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, aspxgridview

I would like to convert my GridView to a list with the headers as the first row.

This can convert my GridView into a list without headers.

```
var Result = GridView.Rows.OfType<GridViewRow>().Select(
                        r => r.Cells.OfType<TableCell>().Select(c => c.Text).ToArray()).ToList();
```

I am trying this to convert it back with the headers.

```
var myorgitem = GridView.Rows.OfType<GridViewRow>().Select(
                    r => r.Cells.OfType<TableCell>().ToDictionary(
                        c => ????????????????????, c => (c.Text ?? "").ToString())).ToList();
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for now, but I would love to make it shorter and more efficient. This will convert any Gridview to a list with headers as the first row.

```
protected List<string[]> GridViewToList(GridView gv)
    {
        var mylist = gv.Rows.OfType<GridViewRow>().Select(
                    r => r.Cells.OfType<DataControlFieldCell>().Select(
                        c => c.ContainingField.HeaderText).ToArray()).ToList();
        if (mylist.Count > 1)
            mylist.RemoveRange(1, mylist.Count - 1);

        mylist.AddRange(gv.Rows.OfType<GridViewRow>().Select(
                    r => r.Cells.OfType<DataControlFieldCell>().Select(c => c.Text).ToArray()).ToList());
        return mylist;
    }
```